# Find characters that are NOT in a specific font, colour or size with MS Word's find/replace panel

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, macros, find-and-replace

MS Word allows you to search for characters that are in a specific format (font, colour, size, etc.). Would it be possible, in a similar way, to find characters in a document that are *not* in a specific format? For example: characters that are *not* in Arial, size 10.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of a way as I posted the question: to add to the characters with the format that we do NOT want to find a feature that can be negated. For example, if we want to search for those characters that are not in size 10, we can underline those characters that are in size 10 and then search for those characters that are not underlined.